# Appropriate epoxy to apply to air dam on 2011 F-150

Tags: plastic

[image]I am looking to epoxy a GoPro mount to the upper forward slanting part of the air dam on my 2011 F-150.

I was wondering what kind of epoxy would be best because I understand that some adhesives can affect the characteristics of plastics, and I'd like to ensure that there is no degradation or discoloration around the application area.

(GoPro to be mounted on the plastic piece with the beveled veins just above the air dam, centered on the license plate)

Comment: Any chance you could add some photos showing the area where you want the camera to go? Also how permanent will it be?

Comment: Absolutely, give me a minute. and optimally it would be completely permanent. It will blend in enough that I'm fine with it being affixed as such.

Comment: Would you object to fastening it mechanically? Could you get to the back side of the spot where you'd like to mount it?

Comment: Just added a photo. I may also bolt it to that plastic piece for the sake of redundancy, but otherwise I would use a standard GoPro adhesive mount, and epoxy that to the plastic.

Answer (score 1):

I'll agree with @dlu here ... drill some holes through both the mount and the bumper and mount it tightly. You wouldn't need big honking screws, just a couple long screws with nuts. Use some thread locker on the nuts to keep them in place. Paint the heads black so they become unobtrusive.